# Enseignement en langue anglaise dans une université française

Tags: anglais, france, académique, université

Je sais que la loi Toubon impose beaucoup de restrictions pour protéger en quelque sorte la langue française. Quand j'étais en Allemagne, on m'a dit que l'enseignement en anglais n'était pas assez "tabou" et que de nombreux cours y étaient donnés en anglais et/ou les polycopies/présentations étaient rédigées en anglais.

Quelles sont les règles qui régissent l'enseignement du supérieur (physique, maths, génie, etc.) en anglais ? En France peut-on **officiellement** distribuer des supports de cours en anglais ?  Peut-on préparer des présentations en anglais et effectuer les cours en français ?

Peut-on même donner des cours en anglais ?

Les réponses dépendent-elles du niveau (grandes écoles vs facultés/IUT/etc.) où des régions (ex.: Nord ou Sud de la France; Paris ou province, etc.) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oui, de nombreuses écoles et universités proposent des cours partiellement ou totalement enseignés en anglais.

Le site [Campus France](http://taughtie.campusfrance.org/tiesearch/#/catalog) contient un moteur de recherche permettant de les identifier.

Pour ce qui est de la réglementation, la loi du [22 juillet 2013](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichTexte.do?cidTexte=JORFTEXT000027735009&categorieLien=id) a assoupli la possibilité d'enseigner dans une autre langue que le français:

> I. ― Le premier alinéa du II de l'article L. 121-3 du même code est remplacé par huit alinéas ainsi rédigés :
>
> « La langue de l'enseignement, des examens et concours, ainsi que des thèses et mémoires dans les établissements publics et privés d'enseignement est le français. Des exceptions peuvent être justifiées :
>   « 1° Par les nécessités de l'enseignement des langues et cultures régionales ou étrangères ;
>   « 2° Lorsque les enseignants sont des professeurs associés ou invités étrangers ;
>   « 3° Par des nécessités pédagogiques, lorsque les enseignements sont dispensés dans le cadre d'un accord avec une institution étrangère ou internationale tel que prévu à l'article L. 123-7 ou dans le cadre d'un programme européen ;
>   « 4° Par le développement de cursus et diplômes transfrontaliers multilingues. 
>   « Dans ces hypothèses, les formations d'enseignement supérieur ne peuvent être que partiellement proposées en langue étrangère et à la condition que l'accréditation concernant ces formations fixe la proportion des enseignements à dispenser en français. Le ministre chargé de l'usage de la langue française en France est immédiatement informé des exceptions accordées, de leur délai et de la raison de ces dérogations.
>   « Les étudiants étrangers bénéficiant de formations en langue étrangère suivent un enseignement de langue française lorsqu'ils ne justifient pas d'une connaissance suffisante de cette dernière. Leur niveau de maîtrise suffisante de la langue française est évalué pour l'obtention du diplôme.
>   « Les enseignements proposés permettent aux étudiants francophones d'acquérir la maîtrise de la langue d'enseignement dans laquelle ces cours sont dispensés. » 
>   II. ― Au second alinéa du II du même article L. 121-3, les mots : « cette obligation » sont remplacés par les mots : « l'obligation prévue au premier alinéa ».